# TeamCity Agent Push Failing Across AWS Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, teamcity

We've recently moved our TeamCity server to AWS, but it is managed by a different business unit in my company, therefore we have different AWS accounts. I've gone through our parent company to get VPC peering enabled, so that I can launch EC2 instance build agents.

To simplify: Our TeamCity server is on AWS account A and I'm working on AWS account B, where I want the build agents to launch.

I had no problems doing this back when the server was on-prem, but I'm having real trouble now.

**Good**: I can launch the instances from TeamCity, which is located in the other business unit's account.

**Bad**: I can't get it to progress from there.

I just want to be able to get 'Agent Push' to work right now. Right now, when I try, this is the output I'm given in the web console:

```
[15:12:09]: AgentPush v58406 - Install Agent on remote host
[15:12:09]: Looking for Target Host...
[15:12:09]: Validating TeamCity Server Root URL 'https://teamcity.company.com' ...
[15:12:09]: Starting agent push to 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'(IP: xx.xx.xxx.xxx) using preset 'Amazon Linux' (Username 'ec2-user'. Target platform: 'Unix')
[15:12:09]: Checking Platform...
[15:16:09]: Remote agent installation failed: timeout: socket is not established
```

One more thing: we use direct connect and all private IPs. I'm supplying the private IP to the agent push. This worked when I was running it on-prem.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't get the instances to talk to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup **AWS Cross account access**. More here in docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console